# File not getting downloaded with Spring Post Method

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, react-native

I am trying to expose an api which downloads files can be of different types, I am showing excel for an example. The file is successfully getting downloaded with GET method endpoint but when i do the same with POST method it doesn't download it but i can see contents of the file in network tab as texts. I tried removing all logic and doing it with empty file and it is same. sample code shared. This backend api is getting called from a frontend application page written in REACT.

```
@GetMapping("/downloadGet")
    public void downloadManualBulkRefund1( DownloadRequest 
     downloadRequest,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        FormatterOutputTO output = new FormatterOutputTO();

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
    filename=\"sample_18082023.xlsx\"");

        response.getOutputStream().write(output.getByteStream() != null ? 
     output.getByteStream() : new byte[] {});

        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();

    }
```

For Post method everything is same except it is a post method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your method return type from Void to resource type by mentioning a Generic partof the response entity class. Ref example

```
package net.codejava.upload;
 
import java.io.IOException;
 
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
 

    @RestController
    public class FileDownloadController {
         
        @GetMapping("/downloadFile/{fileCode}")
        public ResponseEntity<?> downloadFile(@PathVariable("fileCode") String fileCode) {
            FileDownloadUtil downloadUtil = new FileDownloadUtil();
             
            Resource resource = null;
            try {
                resource = downloadUtil.getFileAsResource(fileCode);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().build();
            }
             
            if (resource == null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("File not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
             
            String contentType = "application/octet-stream";
            String headerValue = "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"";
             
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, headerValue)
                    .body(resource);       
        }
    }
```

External Ref for more detials : https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/file-download-upload-rest-api-examples

Comment: why is that required?? I am already writing headers for the browser to understand that it has to be downloaded. Also in this example the ResponseEntitiy is sharing a json response not a file. Download is still happening via a GET api.

Comment: Try to return as a resource, instead of doing force flush in your code base